# Determining frame URL for outgoing requests, using WebRequest API

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm using the WebRequest API to modify requests that get sent by Chrome. In order to know how to rewrite the request I would like to know what's the frame URL that caused the outgoing request. I see I can get frame IDs and tab IDs, with which I could send a message to the content script to find out the URI. But since messaging is always asynchronous there seems to be no way to ensure that I get that information before the request gets sent.

This is for a testing tool, not something for regular users, so I wouldn't mind incurring some added latency. Does anyone know if there is there another way to do this? I tried using setTimeout but it's blocked by content security policy. Using referrer doesn't quite cut it because it's not set on HTTP requests coming from an HTTPS frame.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i fully understand what are you trying to accomplish, but here is what i think.

**Scenario**

Main frame google, sub frames facebook and twitter, and you want to modify any requests from the facebook frame !

If that's the case then here is what i am going to try;

1.Register the [onCompleted](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onCompleted) event listener, which will be used to retrieve the completed requests info, i.e. url and frame id, and store them in an array.

2.Register the [onBeforeSendHeaders](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onBeforeSendHeaders) event listener, which will be used to retrieve the request info and compare it against the one you stored in the previous step, if it passed you can modify the headers

***So the code will go like this***

*[onCompleted](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onCompleted)* ({store the info -i.e. url and frame id- in an array},...)

*[onBeforeSendHeaders](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onBeforeSendHeaders)* ({compare the frame id that made the request with the one stored before if they match modify the header},...)

***Difference between your approach and the one i listed***

In your approach you used asynchronous messages to retrieve info about the frame after the requests get sent, in my approach you will have those info ready for you with no need to do any farther messaging, so whenever a request happens you can use them immediately.

Hope you will find this helpful, good-luck.

Comment: Yes, I think that might just work, thanks! I'm not sure there are any guarantees that onCompleted for the frame will run before onBeforeSendHeaders for subresource from that frame, but I can use onBeforeRequest, which should do the trick.